# How can I use a text value as a mathematical operator?

Tags: jquery, function, calculator, keyup

I am trying to build a simple calculator where the user inputs 2 positive numbers and a calculation symbol (+,-,*,/) and on keyup a jQuery script is called to calculate the result and print it out.

I am having a hard time making the script read my symbol and perform the if statements. I have tried including all the numbers in the keyup function or only the last one (the symbol). Nothing works!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#symbol1").keyup(function(){
        var symbol = $("[name='symbol1']").val();
        var fnum = $("[name='fnum']").val();
        var snum = $("[name='snum']").val();
        if(symbol == "+"){
        var result = fnum + snum;
        $("#result").html(result)
        }
        else if(symbol == "-"){
        var result = Math.abs(fnum - snum);
        $("#result").html(result)
        }
        else if(symbol == "*"){
        var result = fnum*snum;
        $("#result").html(result)
        }
        else if(symbol == "/"){
        var result = fnum/snum;
        $("#result").html(result)
        }
        else{alert("Please input a correct math symbol");}
      });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <center>
            <form id="calc">
                        First Number: <input class="calculations" type="text" name="fnum" size="10" required><br>
              <br>
              Second Number:<input class="calculations" type="text" name="snum" size="10" required><br>
              <br>
              Symbol:<input class="calculations" type="text" name="symbol1" size="10" required><br>
            <p>Result is: <input type="text" id=result></p>
              </form>
            </center>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I would expect after a math symbol is pressed that the result would show up but this is not the case. Thanks in advance for every recommendation.
 I already created a simple BMI calculator which works fine with a submit function. But this time I didn't have any luck.
P.S. Sorry if my code is unreadable, I am just starting to learn jQuery!

Comment: What is the value for symbol when you debug the code?

Comment: You could also use the keyUp event parameter to read which key was pressed.

Comment: Hey apparently from the other users' answers I hadn' set correctly my ids in each var! Thanks a lot for taking the time to check my code!

Answer (score 3):

Just a couple of problems in your code

First you were listening for:

```
$("#symbol1").keyup()
```

But you didn't give your "symbol1" input an ID to be recognised by (only a name attribute)

Secondly you were setting html of result, not val, even though result is an input

Finally you need to convert the values for fnum and snum to Number because they are strings (so 4 + 5 would return 45)

Here's a snippet with it working

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#symbol1").keyup(function(){
        var symbol = $("[name='symbol1']").val();
        var fnum = Number($("[name='fnum']").val());
        var snum = Number($("[name='snum']").val());
        if(symbol == "+"){
        var result = fnum + snum;
        $("#result").val(result)
        }
        else if(symbol == "-"){
        var result = Math.abs(fnum - snum);
        $("#result").val(result)
        }
        else if(symbol == "*"){
        var result = fnum*snum;
        $("#result").val(result)
        }
        else if(symbol == "/"){
        var result = fnum/snum;
        $("#result").val(result)
        }
        else{alert("Please input a correct math symbol");}
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
            <center>
            <form id="calc">
                        First Number: <input class="calculations" type="text" name="fnum" size="10" required><br>
              <br>
              Second Number:<input class="calculations" type="text" name="snum" size="10" required><br>
              <br>
              Symbol:<input class="calculations" type="text" name="symbol1" size="10" required id="symbol1"><br>
            <p>Result is: <input type="text" id=result></p>
              </form>
            </center>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector expects an ID, not a name.

```
<input class="calculations" type="text" id="symbol1" size="10" required>
// --------------------------------------^
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/7esLohzb/)

Νίκος Τιτομιχελάκης pointed out that you need to convert your strings to numbers. Also, define `result` outside the `if` statement so you don't have to initialize it repeatedly, and set the text value in the page once, also outside the `if` statement.

Also also, alerts are a pain, both for you as the developer and for users. jQuery makes it easy to put messages in the page, as I've done in my demo.

Answer (score 0):

There's few things missing, and your code is readable :) plnkr link with updated code

```
var symbol = $("[name='symbol1']").val();
var fnum = $("[name='fnum']").val();
var snum = $("[name='snum']").val();               
if(symbol == "+"){
  var result = fnum + snum;
  $("#result").val(result)
 }

 <p>Result is: <input type="text" id="result"></p>
```

// quotes above------------------------------------^-----^

full code 
https://plnkr.co/edit/SLyOZEE6WQRnygfHPJix?p=preview

Comment: Note to both of you, since you're both new. "Thank you" and "you're welcome" comments are discouraged as we're not a discussion forum. Use votes instead.

Comment: I would but I cannot use points until I have some credibility. But I will keep it in mind for the next one.